# ERROR! conflicting action statements: command, debug

Tags: bash, ansible

I am looking to execute a remote shell script and get the output. The confliction occurs in the **tasks/build.yml** file:

```
- name: Execute setup.sh in Git repository
  command: chdir=/opt/{{ repo_name }} {{ item }}
  with_items:
   - ./setup.sh

  register: command_output
  debug:
   var: command_output.stdout_lines
```

Here is  main.yml:

```
---
- name: Clone and Build Project
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true

  vars_files:
   - vars/gitlab.yml

  tasks:
    - include: tasks/clone.yml
    - include: tasks/dependencies.yml
    - include: tasks/build.yml
```

The playbook executes successfully w/o debugging information. After I try to output debug info it fails with that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two tasks, you need to use `register` for 1st task and `debug` it in 2nd task. Also notice that, you are using `with_items` this means, you will have to use `debug` over `<registername>.results[<item>].stdout_lines`

```
- name: Execute setup.sh in Git repository
  command: chdir=/opt/{{ repo_name }} {{ item }}
  with_items:
   - ./setup.sh
  register: command_output

-  debug:
   var: command_output.results[0].stdout_lines
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks for your help!